# Listar arquivos pelo nome (que contem data), mas filtrando os 5 dias anteriores a data atual com .bat?

Tags: script, cmd, batch, bat

Estou tentando fazer algo que talvez nem seja possível fazer em **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)** mas especifico usando findstr?

Tenho uma dezena de arquivos nesse layout: **nomedoarquivo_ano_mes_dia_hora.pdf**

De forma que, a data como dia e mês contento dois dígitos e o ano com quatro dígito, o nome do arquivo e o formato da data contem underline, dias e meses menores que 10 contem 0 na frente.

Preciso que o script que conseguisse pegar pelo menos o dia no nome do arquivo.

**Obs.:** Já consegui pegar pela data de modificação porem nesse caso preciso a data que esta no nome do arquivo.

Além disso/, preciso gerar um arquivo.log ou um aviso de alerta informando os arquivos que estariam desatualizados com um limite de 5 dias pregressos a data atual.

É possível algo assim usando **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**?

Comment: bom dia , sim tem underline entre(*nomedoarquivo)_(ano)_(mes)_dia_(hora) e na hora sem pontos ou traços ou underline seria junto!

Comment: mostre o que você já fez...além disso, **coloque um exemplo da linha que você quer tratar**, fica muito mais fácil de entender do que ler uma explicação do formato da linha, e coloque um exemplo da linha de log que você quer ter

Comment: Claro que é possível fazer em bat - mas é o tipo de problema que é melhor resolvido em uma linguagem de mais alto nível, que tenha uma melhor separação entre dados  e parâemtros de comandos. O mesmo problema em Python, por exemplo,  seria resolvido por um programa que ficaria muito mais legível e menor. Provavelmente em visual basic também

Comment: Não entendo, tudo é resolvido com linguagem de alto nível, sem duvida, porque não excluir :as tags: cmd/bat/batch/script/etc...Porque as perguntas são aceitas, e não são fechadas? Não é o caso de resolver o problema, é o caso de **assim** resolver o problema.

Comment: @jsbueno o op especificou .bat. Se começar-mos a escolher a linguagem e o sistema em que vamos dar as respostas todas as perguntas terão que ser fechadas por serem amplas demais ou por serem de caráter subjetivo pois por exemplo eu não acho que em *Python* se consiga uma boa resposta eu acredito que em *PHP* eu consiga uma resposta superior ao *Python*. Então logo em seguida surgirá outro op que alegará que em *Java* consegue-se uma resposta superior eliminado-se assim a necessidade das tags.

Comment: Entendo ter no bat uma dificuldade que não é reconhecida, pessoal usa o powershel, sim, é mais fácil, sim, tem infinitos recursos, sim, mas ignoram, não reconhecem, a dificuldade que é responder usando um interpretador de comandos com sua limitações.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

---

**Sim**, é possível obter as datas e os nomes dos arquivos 
 anteriores 05 dias pregresso a data atual via bat/cmd:

1. Lê a **data** do sistema e transformamos em números: `2019/01/01 = 20190101`
2. Esse número **subtraímos** o número da **data - 05 dias**: `20190101-20181227=8874`
3. Fazemos o mesmo com todos os **meses** obtendo os dias a subtrair mês a mês
4. Dai filtrando via `for` *looping* o que for **menor/igual a 05** e **maior/igual a 06**
5. Usamos um *loop* `for` **(4 + 2020 até 2100)**, para **comparar** se o **ano atual é bissexto**
6. Num *array*: `Mês=_i Dias_Subtrair=_j` `set _m_d=01-8874,02-75,03-!_f!..`
7. As **variáveis mês-dia comparadas** com a posição `%%i-%%j`, dá quanto **subtrair**
8. Daí, se o **dia** é **menor que 06**, **subtrair** o `%%j`, senão, **subtrair** `1`

> **Observações:**
>
> 1. **Arquivo.log** será **criado** na pasta **%temp%** e **movida** para pasta `!_path_pdf!`
> 2. Conteúdo do **arquivo.log** será copiado para o seu **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>**
> 3. **Edite o comando:** `Set "_path_pdf=."` 
>      
>     Substituindo o valor: `=.` por `=drive:\pasta\onde\tem\os\pdfs` 
>     De forma que fique: `set "_path_pdf=drive:\pasta\onde\tem\os\pdfs"`

---

Script **-05_dias.cmd**:

---

```
@echo off && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 

rem :: Edite variavel _path_pdf substituindo por drive/pasta/dos/seus/pdf's ::
cd /d "%~dp0" && set "_path_pdf=." && cd /d "!_path_pdf!"

rem :: Compondo string para uso com findstr onde verifica ano atual/bisexto ::
for /l %%l in (2020 4 2100)do set _b6to=!_b6to!%%l,
set "_do=wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year" 

rem :: Obtendo a data com layout previsível e sem possível customização do usurario :: 
for /f "tokens=1-3delims= " %%a in ('!_do!^|findstr /r [0-9]')do ( 
     set "_y=%%c" & set "_dd=0%%a" & set "_mm=0%%b" & set "_m=!_mm:~-2!" 
     set "_d=!_dd:~-2!" & set "_dt=!_y!_!_m!_!_d!" & set "_dt_str=!_y!!_m!!_d!"
    ) && set /a "_loop=1!_d!-101" & set "_cnt=0" & set "_log=%temp%\!_dt!.log"

rem :: Compondo um "pseudo" array para uso em alguns loopings for junto call :^[  ::
rem :: Observando que o 01 = mes c 2 digitos e o 8875, são os dias para subtrair  ::
rem :: os dias/datas pregressas tratadas como mumeros. 20190105 -8875 = 20181231  ::
rem :: Procurando ano bisexto na string com findstr para verificar se ano bisexto ::
echo/!_b6to!|findstr /lic:"!_y!,">nul && set /a "_f=77" || set /a "_f=78"
set "_m_d=01-8874,02-75,03-!_f!,04-75,05-76,06-75,07-76,08-75,09-75,10-75,11-75,12-76"

rem :: Identificando mes/dias quantitativos para subtrair na data atual -05 dias ::
for %%~ in (!_m_d!)do for /f "tokens=1,2delims=-" %%i in ('echo/%%~')do ( 
     if 1!_d! gtr 105 if /i [%%i] equ [!_m!] call :^] %%j "5 -1 1" 5 & goto :^)
     if 1!_d! leq 105 if /i [%%i] equ [!_m!] call :^] %%j "1 +1 5" 1 & goto :^)
    )

:^]
rem :: 1) Datas sendo subtraidas para obter intervalo de 05 dias anteriores a !_dt! ::
rem :: 2) Compondo layout/pattern do intervalo de datas e buscas dos Arquivos .PDFs ::
rem :: 3) Buscando e registrando resultados obtidos no Arquivo log %temp%\!_dt!.log ::
echo/Listagem do^(s^) Arquivo^(s^) Desatualizados em !_dt:_=/!:>"!_log!" && for /l %%l in (%~2)do (
     if %%l leq !_loop! (set /a "_d[%%l]=!_dt_str!-%%l") else (set /a "_d[%%l]=!_dt_str!-%1" & set /a "_dt_str+=1")
     set "_str_%%l=!_d[%%l]!" & call set "_str_%%l=*_!_str_%%l:~,4!_!_str_%%l:~4,2!_!_str_%%l:~-2!_*.pdf"
     if /i exist ".\!_str_%%l!" where .:"!_str_%%l!">>!_log!
    )
rem :: 4) Listando os resultados das acoes e portando dados p/ crtl+c/ctrl+v e tela ::
for /f "tokens=*delims=:" %%i in ('type "!_log!"^|find /c ".pdf"')do set "_cnt=%%i"
>> !_log! echo/Total de Arquivo^(s^) Desatualizado^(s^): !_cnt! && type "!_log!" | clip
>nul move /y "!_log!" . && exit /b 

:^)
type ".\!_dt!.log" && endlocal & goto :eof
```

**Resultado**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

#### Usando um bat que muda a data várias vezes e testando as sáidas/dias:

**<sup>Necessário credencial de administrador</sup>**

**Obs.:** O **`for`** no formato data do meu sistema, verifique o seu pelo cmd: **`date <nul|find "("`**

Se necessário mude no **`(10-01-2018 12-05-2018 21-05-2018 05-01-2019 01-10-2019 05-12-2019)`** alterando para conformidade do seu sistema.

```cmd
@echo off && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
mode con cols=60 lines=15 & title SO_pt-BR_Q376119 
rem :: data no formato yyyy-mm-dd, apenas altere para o layout de seu sistema: 
for %%i in (10-01-2018 12-05-2018 21-05-2018 05-01-2019 01-10-2019 05-12-2019)do (
    >nul date %%i 
    echo/Data em !date! & call :SO_pt-BR_Q376119
    )
:SO_pt-BR_Q376119
@echo off && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
set "_pdf_folder=." && cd /d "!_pdf_folder!"
for /l %%l in (2020 4 2100)do set _b6to=!_b6to!%%l,
set "_do=wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year"
for /f "tokens=1-3delims= " %%a in ('!_do!^|findstr /r [0-9]')do ( 
     set "_y=%%c" & set "_dd=0%%a" & set "_mm=0%%b" & set "_m=!_mm:~-2!" 
     set "_d=!_dd:~-2!" & set "_dt=!_y!_!_m!_!_d!" & set "_dt_str=!_y!!_m!!_d!"
    ) && set /a "_loop=1!_d!-101" & set "_cnt=0" & set "_log=%temp%\!_dt!.log"
echo/!_b6to!|findstr /lic:"!_y!,">nul && set /a "_f=77" || set /a "_f=78"
set "_m_d=01-8874,02-75,03-!_f!,04-75,05-76,06-75,07-76,08-75,09-75,10-75,11-75,12-76"
for %%~ in (!_m_d!)do for /f "tokens=1,2delims=-" %%i in ('echo/%%~')do ( 
     if 1!_d! gtr 105 if /i [%%i] equ [!_m!] call :^] %%j "5 -1 1" 5 & goto :^)
     if 1!_d! leq 105 if /i [%%i] equ [!_m!] call :^] %%j "1 +1 5" 1 & goto :^))
:^]
echo/Listagem do^(s^) Arquivo^(s^) Desatualizados em !_dt:_=/!:>"!_log!" && for /l %%l in (%~2)do (
    if %%l leq !_loop! (set /a "_d[%%l]=!_dt_str!-%%l") else (set /a "_d[%%l]=!_dt_str!-%1" & set /a "_dt_str+=1")
    set "_str_%%l=!_d[%%l]!" & call set "_str_%%l=*_!_str_%%l:~,4!_!_str_%%l:~4,2!_!_str_%%l:~-2!_*.pdf"
    if /i exist ".\!_str_%%l!" where .:"!_str_%%l!">>!_log!
    )
for /f "tokens=*delims=:" %%i in ('type "!_log!"^|find /c ".pdf"')do set "_cnt=%%i"
>>!_log! echo/Total de Arquivo^(s^) Desatualizado^(s^): !_cnt! |clip  & exit /b 

:^)
type "!_log!" & timeout /t 7 >nul & cls & endlocal && exit/b
```

**Resultado**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> **Update** - Para os interessados na **recompensa**
>
> **Abaixo um gerador de arquivos pdf** que obedecem o layout da pergunta.
>
> **Observações:**
>
> 1. Para gerar em **anos anteriores** é só mudar a data no sistema para **ano desejado**
> 2. Gera arquivos em modo **.txt** renomeados p **.pdf** de **2019-01-01** até **2019-12-31**
> 3. Após gerar os arquivos é possível testar as saídas das respostas postadas.

Script **gera_pdf.cmd**:

```vb
@echo off && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 

set "_do=wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year" & for /l %%l in (2020 4 2100)do set "_leap=!_leap!%%l,"
for /f "tokens=1-3delims= " %%a in ('!_do!^|findstr /r [0-9]')do set "_y=%%c" & set "_dd=0%%a" & set "_mm=0%%b"
set "_m=!_mm:~-2!" && set "_d=!_dd:~-2!" && set "_dt=!_y!_!_m!_!_d!" && set /a "_l=!_mm:~1!-1" && set /a "_int=0"
echo/!_leap!|findstr /lic:"!_y!," >nul && (set /a _f=2, _fev=29, _ano=366) || (set /a _f=3, _fev=28, _ano=365) 
set "_m_d=01-31,02-!_fev!,03-31,04-30,05-31,06-30,07-31,08-31,09-30,10-31,11-30,12-31" & set "_log=%temp%\!_dt!.log"
set "_i=-1" & set "_soma=# 0 !_f! 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0" & call set "_soma=!_soma!" && set "_soma=%_soma: ="
set /a _i+=1&set "_soma!_i!=%" && set /a _soma=0, _alvo=0&& for /l %%S in (0 1 !_l!)do if not "%%S" == "!_l!" (set /a "_soma+=%%S") else set /a _cnt=%%S * 31 - !_soma!
call set /a "_alvo=!_cnt! + !_dd:~1! - 6" && set "_p=!_dd:~1!" & set /a "_cnt+=!_p!" & for %%I in (!_m_d!)do (
for /f "tokens=1,2delims=-" %%i in ('echo/%%I')do for /l %%x in (1 1 %%j)do set /a "_int+=1" & (
     if %%x leq 9 (set "_x=%%i_0%%x" & set "_a=0%%x!_a!") else (set "_x=%%i_%%j" & set "_a=%%x!_a!")
     call set _random=%random% && call echo/where .:*_!_y!_%%i_!_a:~0,2!_!_x:_=!.pdf >"!_random: =!_!_y!_%%i_!_a:~0,2!_%%i%%j.pdf"
     ))
)
```

### - - -

> Update: *sem comentários e portado para arquivos* de qualquer extensão, apenas e use a variável **`set _ext=pdf`**, trocando o valor **`pdf`** pela extensão desejada, observando de não usar **"."** na variável.

---

```
@echo off && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "_ext=pdf" & set "_do=wmic Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Month^,Year" 
cd /d "%~dp0" && set "_path_pdf=." && cd /d "!_path_pdf!" 
for /l %%l in (2020 4 2100)do set _b6to=!_b6to!%%l,
for /f "tokens=1-3delims= " %%a in ('!_do!^|findstr /r [0-9]')do ( 
     set "_y=%%c" & set "_dd=0%%a" & set "_mm=0%%b" & set "_m=!_mm:~-2!"
     set "_d=!_dd:~-2!" & set "_dt=!_y!_!_m!_!_d!" & set "_dt_str=!_y!!_m!!_d!"
    ) && set /a "_loop=1!_d!-101" & set "_cnt=0" & set "_log=%temp%\!_dt!.log"  
echo/!_b6to!|findstr /lic:"!_y!,">nul && set /a "_f=77" || set /a "_f=78"
set "_m_d=01-8874,02-75,03-!_f!,04-75,05-76,06-75,07-76,08-75,09-75,10-75,11-75,12-76"
for %%~ in (!_m_d!)do for /f "tokens=1,2delims=-" %%i in ('echo/%%~')do (
     if 1!_d! gtr 105 if /i [%%i] equ [!_m!] call :^] %%j "5 -1 1" 5 & goto :^)
     if 1!_d! leq 105 if /i [%%i] equ [!_m!] call :^] %%j "1 +1 5" 1 & goto :^)
    )
:^]
echo/Listagem do^(s^) Arquivo^(s^) Desatualizados em !_dt:_=/!:>"!_log!" && for /l %%l in (%~2)do (
     if %%l leq !_loop! (set /a "_d[%%l]=!_dt_str!-%%l") else (set /a "_d[%%l]=!_dt_str!-%1" & set /a "_dt_str+=1")
     set "_str_%%l=!_d[%%l]!" & call set "_str_%%l=*_!_str_%%l:~,4!_!_str_%%l:~4,2!_!_str_%%l:~-2!_*.!_ext!" 
     if /i exist ".\!_str_%%l!" where .:"!_str_%%l!">>!_log!
    )
for /f "tokens=*delims=:" %%i in ('type "!_log!"^|find /c ".!_ext!"')do set "_cnt=%%i"
>> !_log! echo/Total de Arquivo^(s^) Desatualizado^(s^): !_cnt! && clip <"!_log!"
>nul move /y "!_log!" . & exit /b 

:^)
type ".\!_dt!.log" && endlocal & goto :eof
```

---

Comment: Essa resposta é a correta para pergunta. Foi feita no *CMD* como op especificou e realmente busca por arquivos desatualizados.

Comment: Registre em log os arquivos dos últimos 5 dias, não do mês/ano anteriores etc..

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas

Comment: Ola @ItWasn'tMe, tentei melhorar sua edição, se você achar que ficou estranho ou qualquer outro motivo, você pode entrar [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/379923/revisions) é clicar em reverter =P

Comment: @IcaroMartins, È a primeira vez que algum operado edita uma resposta minha, obrigado, fica assim!

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe para adaptar esse script para buscar arquivos cujas as extensões seja diferente a .pdf  é so modificar aonde tem .pdf e substituir para a extensão desejada como por exemplo os mesmo formatado e etc porem .FDB como seria ?

Comment: @Walisson Boa noite, editado para atender qualquer extensão, para isso é só editar a variável **`_ext`**!! Sem o • (ponto)!!

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe ok nao tinha percebido que tinha deixado explicito isso no inicio da sua explicação ... aproveitando a deixa , para pesquisar em subdiretórios  o que precisaria ser alterado ? Pois assim só enxerga em diretórios.

Comment: @Walisson Boa noite tchê, troque onde tens: **where .:** por **where /r .**  na linha 20 do primeiro código na postagem, vai ficar assim: **`where /r . "!_str_%%l!" >>"!_log!"`**

Comment: @Walisson Postei na dúvida se tinhas ou n visto, daí comentei...

Answer (score 7):

Essa pergunta é interessante como desafio, na prática é totalmente inviável, o script é complicado e muito fácil de quebrar.

*Update: está faltando consistência dos nomes dos arquivos, se ano, mês e dia do mês são válidos.*

Aqui vai uma solução que criei, pelo desafio:

```
@echo off

:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

:: dias do mes - ano nao bissexto

set mes_1_n=31
set mes_2_n=28
set mes_3_n=31
set mes_4_n=30
set mes_5_n=31
set mes_6_n=30
set mes_7_n=31
set mes_8_n=31
set mes_9_n=30
set mes_10_n=31
set mes_11_n=30
set mes_12_n=31

:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

:: dias do mes - ano bissexto

set mes_1_b=31
set mes_2_b=29
set mes_3_b=31
set mes_4_b=30
set mes_5_b=31
set mes_6_b=30
set mes_7_b=31
set mes_8_b=31
set mes_9_b=30
set mes_10_b=31
set mes_11_b=30
set mes_12_b=31

:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

:: pega data de hoje no formato d/m/a
set data_hoje=%date%

:: separa data_hoje em dia mes ano
for /f "delims=/ tokens=1,2,3" %%a in ("%data_hoje%") do (
  set DIA_HOJE=%%a
  set MES_HOJE=%%b
  set ANO_HOJE=%%c
)
:: echo ano_hoje=[%ANO_HOJE%] mes_hoje=[%MES_HOJE%] dia_hoje=[%DIA_HOJE%]

:: verifica se o ano atual e` bissexto (para fazer a contagem dos dias do ano)
call :VER_SE_ANO_BISSEXTO ANO_BISSEXTO_HOJE %ANO_HOJE%
:: echo ANO_BISSEXTO_HOJE=%ANO_BISSEXTO_HOJE%

:: calcula o dia do ano hoje
call :DIAS_ANO %ANO_HOJE% %MES_HOJE% %DIA_HOJE% %ANO_BISSEXTO_HOJE% DIAS_ANO_HOJE

:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

:: filtra nomes de arquivos
dir /b | findstr /r "[^_]*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9].pdf" > nomes_validos.txt

:: separa por dia mes ano, e processa cada nome de arquivo
for /f "delims=_ tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%e in (nomes_validos.txt) do (
  rem echo nome=%%e ano=%%f mes=%%g dia=%%h
  call :PROCESSA_ARQ %%e %%f %%g %%h %%i
)

goto :EOF

:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

:PROCESSA_ARQ

set _NOME=%1
set _ANO=%2
set _MES=%3
set _DIA=%4
set _HORA=%5

set _NOME_COMPLETO=%_NOME%_%_ANO%_%_MES%_%_DIA%_%_HORA% 
echo processando %_NOME_COMPLETO%

:: verifica se ano do arquivo e` bissexto, deixa resultado na variavel ANO_BISSEXTO_ARQ
call :VER_SE_ANO_BISSEXTO ANO_BISSEXTO_ARQ %_ANO%
:: echo ANO_BISSEXTO_ARQ=%ANO_BISSEXTO_ARQ%

:: calcula dias do ano
:: echo -- %_ANO% / %_MES% / %_DIA% / %ANO_BISSEXTO_ARQ% / DIAS_ANO_ARQ
call :DIAS_ANO %_ANO% %_MES% %_DIA% %ANO_BISSEXTO_ARQ% DIAS_ANO_ARQ
:: echo @@@ _ANO=%_ANO% ANO_HOJE=%ANO_HOJE% DIAS_ANO_HOJE=%DIAS_ANO_HOJE% DIAS_ANO_ARQ=%DIAS_ANO_ARQ%

if %_ANO% neq %ANO_HOJE% goto :PROCESSA_ARQ_OLD

set /a DIF_DIAS=DIAS_ANO_HOJE-DIAS_ANO_ARQ
:: echo === DIAS_ANO_HOJE=%DIAS_ANO_HOJE% DIAS_ANO_ARQ=%DIAS_ANO_ARQ% %DIF_DIAS%
if %DIF_DIAS% gtr 5 (
  echo !!! %_NOME_COMPLETO% esta' desatualizado
) else (
  echo *** %_NOME_COMPLETO% esta' atualizado
)
goto :EOF

:PROCESSA_ARQ_OLD

:: echo old

set /a _DIF_ANOS=ANO_HOJE-_ANO
:: echo @@@ ANO_HOJE=%ANO_HOJE% ANO=%_ANO% _DIF_ANOS=%_DIF_ANOS%
if %_DIF_ANOS% gtr 1 (
  echo !!! %_NOME_COMPLETO% esta' desatualizado
  goto :EOF
)

set /a DIF_DIAS_ARQ=365-%DIAS_ANO_ARQ%
if %ANO_BISSEXTO_ARQ%==1 (set /a DIF_DIAS_ARQ+=1)

set /a DIF_DIAS_ARQ+=DIAS_ANO_HOJE

if %DIF_DIAS_ARQ% gtr 5 (
  echo !!! %_NOME_COMPLETO% esta' desatualizado
) else (
  echo *** %_NOME_COMPLETO% esta' atualizado
)

goto :EOF

:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157817/batch-file-leap-year

:VER_SE_ANO_BISSEXTO

set _NOME_VAR=%1
set _ANO=%2

set /A "_BISSEXTO=!(_ANO%%4) + (!!(_ANO%%100)-!!(_ANO%%400))"
if %_BISSEXTO% equ 1 (set %_NOME_VAR%=1) else (set %_NOME_VAR%=0)

goto :EOF

:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

:DIAS_ANO

set _ANO=%1
set _MES=%2
set _DIA=%3
set _ANO_BISSEXTO=%4

:: echo _ANO=%_ANO%
:: echo _MES=%_MES%
:: echo _DIA=%_DIA%

:: nome da variavel que vai conter o resultado
set _NOME_VAR=%5

if %_ANO_BISSEXTO%==1 (set _FLAG_B=b) else (set _FLAG_B=n)

set _N_ACUM_DIAS=0

set _N_MES=1

:: elimina zeros `a esquerda (vi em algum lugar no stackoverflow.com)
SET /a _MES=1%_MES%-(11%_MES%-1%_MES%)/10
:: echo ### _MES=%_MES%
:: -----

:: soma os dias dos meses anteriores, mais a data de hoje
:: por exemplo 1/mai/2019
:: 31 (jan) + 27 (fev) + 31 (mar) + 30 (abr) + 1 (mai) = 120

:LOOP_DIAS_ANO

:: echo === _N_MES=%_N_MES% _MES=%_MES%
if %_N_MES% equ %_MES% goto :FIM_LOOP_DIAS_ANO

set _NOME_MES=mes_%_N_MES%_%_FLAG_B%
call set _DIAS_MES=%%%_NOME_MES%%%
:: echo _NOME_MES=%_NOME_MES% _DIAS_MES=%_DIAS_MES%

set /a _N_ACUM_DIAS+=%_DIAS_MES%
:: echo ano=%_ANO% mes=%_N_MES% dias=%_DIAS_MES% dias_acumulados=%_N_ACUM_DIAS%
set /a _N_MES+=1
goto :LOOP_DIAS_ANO

:: -----

:FIM_LOOP_DIAS_ANO

:: echo dias_acumulados 1: %_N_ACUM_DIAS%

set /a _N_ACUM_DIAS+=%_DIA%
:: echo dias_acumulados 2: %_N_ACUM_DIAS%

set %_NOME_VAR%=%_N_ACUM_DIAS%

goto :EOF

:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Ficou faltando mostrar o teste, mas já fechei a vm Windows, depois coloco. :)

Comment: Eita! Complicado até eh, mas a parte ` fácil de quebrar` n tendi?

Comment: batch é muito fácil de quebrar, qualquer mexidinha é arriscada

Comment: Então como em qualquer linguagem a edição em potencial resulta em possível “quebra”.

Comment: estou falando da minha solução, embora de maneira geral seja difícil criar scripts complexos em batch que sejam robustos

Comment: A sua a minha, tem lá complexidade, em bat, n tem p onde correr, n há métodos prontos, funções, etc,, to no mobile, depois vou ver  e tentar entender.

Comment: Uma coisa n entendi de sua edição, porque não por a tag cmd?

Comment: não tinha a tag cmd na pergunta original...agora tem, coloquei...ps. nunca faço nada no celular a não ser ouvir música e ler (e eventualmente fazer e receber ligações, o que é raro)

Comment: Entendo seu comentário na resposta como algo conflitante, ‘na prática eh totalmente inviável`. Visto os resultados postados( imagens) + a aceitação do operador. Também 1/2 agressivo, e não vejo como algo necessário, mas, enfim, poderia explicar esse ponto/tema melhor? Perdoe, queria entender o seu ponto de vista.

Comment: A pergunta tem utilidade na prática, inclusive pode ser portada p variações de dias, p mais e p menos. A aceitação responde pela utilidade + a votação up recebida, ou ignorou esses dados?

Comment: dias de fevereiro: engano :)

Comment: @zentrunix Com o seu código incrementei  /a /-p /o:n /s /b  na parte que " :: filtra nomes de arquivos" para alem de buscar nas pastas também buscar em subpastas, ordenar e trazer o caminho o qual o arquivo se encontra porem o script quebra e trás os aquivos que não entraria na lista , sem esse incremento ele funciona porem somente no diretório aonde esta o script .

Comment: @Wallsson por favor, crie uma pergunta específica sobre isso

Comment: @zentrunix seu script busca somente em pastas, não consegue enxergar os arquivos buscado em subpastas das pastas! Pode ser por conta que atualmente esta somente " dir /b " porem ao modificar essa parte substituir o '"/b " por " /s " o script quebra

Answer (score 6):

Não sei se entendi bem a sua questão, seria interessante colocar alguns exemplos dos nomes de arquivos e do resultado esperado, mas vou tentar ajudar da forma como entendi e talvez isso já te oriente um pouco.

Em .bat as coisas são um pouco limitadas e não sei se seria possível ou não resolver com ele, mas acredito que provavelmente não teremos problemas em utilizar o PowerShell do Windows (a versão "turbinada" do batch).

Supondo que os seus arquivos seguem o seguinte patrão de nome: **NOME_ANO_MES_DIA_HHMM.pdf**. Podemos "quebrar" o nome do arquivo em cada um dos underlines e guardar os pedaços em um array. No PowerShell isso é feito com o Split ([documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6)). Depois podemos acessar cada um dos pedaços e recriar uma string somente com a data, em um formato padronizado, para que seja possível trabalhar com elas de forma mais fácil. O PowerShell possuí recursos nativos para trabalhar com datas, parecido com C#.

Fiz um pequeno script para trabalhar dessa forma e acredito que seja mais ou menos o que você está buscando. Ele irá listar todos os arquivos (*.pdf) do diretório (o mesmo onde o script está) e depois irá percorrer cada um deles, extraindo as informações da data e montando uma string no formato mes/dia/ano e verificando se a diferença em dias é maior ou igual 5, tendo como referência a data atual do sistema. Caso seja, o nome do arquivo é gravado no log.
É importante notar que caso o padrão do nome dos arquivos seja diferente do meu exemplo o script não vai funcionar e deverá ser adequado, basicamente modificando a linha onde a data e extraída(`$fileDate = $file.Split("_")[2] + "/" + $file.Split("_")[3] + "/" + $file.Split("_")[1]`).
Obs. O padrão do horário, nesse caso, é irrelevante.

Exemplo:
Arquivo1_2019_04_17_1425.pdf
Arquivo2_2019_04_18_0921.pdf
Arquivo3_2019_04_20_0830.pdf
Arquivo4_2019_04_23_0900.pdf
Arquivo5_2019_03_03_0900.pdf
Arquivo6_201903030900.pdf

```
$actualDate = Get-Date 
$files = ls -n *.pdf
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"

Write-Output("**************************") >> log.txt
Write-Output("Inicio do log: $actualDate") >> log.txt
Write-Output("**************************") >> log.txt

foreach ($file in $files) {
    try {
        $fileDate = $file.Split("_")[2] + "/" + $file.Split("_")[3] + "/" + $file.Split("_")[1]
        $fileDate = [datetime]$fileDate
        $diff = $actualDate - $fileDate
        if ($diff.Days -ge 5) {
            $file >> log.txt
        }    
    } Catch {
        Write-Output("Falha ao obter a data do nome do arquivo: $file") >> log.txt    
    }
}
```

Supondo que a data atual do sistema seja 23/04/2019, o resultado do log seria esse:

```
**************************
Inicio do log: 04/23/2019 12:28:15
**************************
Falha ao obter a data do nome do arquivo: AAlog - Copia.txt
Arquivo1_2019_04_17_1425.txt
Arquivo2_2019_04_18_0921.txt
Arquivo5_2019_03_03_0900.txt
Falha ao obter a data do nome do arquivo: Arquivo6_201903030900.txt
```

Para utilizar o PowerShell você pode utilizar o próprio bloco de notas e salvar o arquivo com a extensão *.ps1 e depois executa-lo clicando com o botão direito do mouse no arquivo e "Executar com o PowerShell". Também é possível utilizar o *Windows PowerShell ISE* ([documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/scripting/components/ise/windows-powershell-integrated-scripting-environment--ise-?view=powershell-6)), que é o ambiente para desenvolvimento de Scripts nativo do Windows.

Answer (score 2):

O **PowerShell** pode cumprir com a tarefa de forma bem mais rápida e simples.

```
#criando no ambiente uma variável para salvar os nome dos arquivos
$Log = $Env:temp+"\"+(get-date -Format d)+".log"
# caso ocorra uma mais de uma execução, apaga o conteúdo anterior do log
if (Test-Path -Path "$Log") {clear-content -Path "$Log" -Force}
# cria a primeira linha para o log com data no mesmo formato dos arquivos
$Hoje = "Arquivos desatualizados em: "+(get-date -format d)
$Hoje | Out-File -FilePath $Log -append 
# implementando um loop for de 1 a 5 dias para obtenção datas anteriores o mesmo formato dos arquivos
    For ($i=1; $i -le 5; $i++) {
    $File = $(Get-Date).addDays(-$i).ToString("yyyy_MM_dd")
    $List = "*"+$file+"*.pdf"
    # listagem dos possíveis arquivos presentes na pasta escrendo a saída no log
    ls -n "*$file*.pdf" | Out-File -FilePath $Log -Append  
    }
# contagem dos arquivos com datas anteriores encontrados dentro do log 
$Pdf = $(gc $Log -filter ".pdf").count ; "Total de arquivos desatualizado:"+$Pdf | Out-File -FilePath $Log -append 
Out-File -FilePath $Log -append ; Get-Content "$Log"
# listagem do conteúdo do log na tela (stdout)
```

Existe a opção de usar as **`Alias`** no **script**, ficando da forma abaixo:

```
# Mesmo código em formato compacto fazendo uso de Alias:
#--------------------------------------------------------
$Log=$Env:temp+"\"+(get-date -F d)+".log";if (Test-Path -Path "$Log"){clc -Path "$Log" -Force};$Hoje="Arquivos desatualizados em: "+(get-date -f d);$hoje|Out-File -FilePath $Log -Append
For ($i=1; $i -le 5; $i++) {$File = $(Get-Date).AddDays(-$i).ToString("yyyy_MM_dd");$List = "*"+$File+"*.pdf";ls -n "*$File*.pdf"|Out-File -FilePath $Log -Append};$pdf=$(gc $Log -Filter ".pdf").Count
"Total de arquivos desatualizado: "+$pdf|Out-File -FilePath $Log -Append; Out-File -FilePath $Log -Append;gc "$Log"

# Alias ultilizadas no PS1:
#--------------------------
# -f  |  -Format (Get-Date)
# clc |  Clear-Content
# gc  |  Get-Content
```